# Why do my program with many forks not stop?

Tags: fork

The Program which has many forks as below **did not finish**.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
  static int fork_cnt = 0;
  const unsigned kCnt = 4;

  for (int i = 0; i < kCnt; ++i) {
    fork();
  }
  std::cout << "fork_cnt=" << fork_cnt << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I ran it, It stop as below. It seems that The main fork is finished, but other program is waitting for something.

```
fork_cnt=0
qingfeng@ubuntu:~$ fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
fork_cnt=0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the program is not waiting for anything. What happens here is that you create child processes, that detach from your current stdin (at least I believe they do given their behavior). When your original process returns, sh regains the control over your stdin and prompts you for input - hence the `qingfeng@ubuntu:~$` in the second line of your second listing. Anyway, your child processes keep writing to stdout, therefor the `fork_cnt=0`are output after the `qingfeng@ubuntu:~$`. When all processes have ended `sh` sees no reason for prompting you again for an input, therefor it seems to you as if the program's still running, but if you entered some command (or just hit `Enter`) you'd see it did.

To test this, please try the following: Create an infinite loop in each child process right after its creation.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
  static int fork_cnt = 0;
  const unsigned kCnt = 4;

  for (int i = 0; i < kCnt; ++i) {
    int pid = fork();
    while(pid == 0);
  }
  std::cout << "fork_cnt=" << fork_cnt << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now `fork_cnt=0` is output only once and you regain the control over the terminal.

```
paul@www:~/Programming/playground/fork# ./a.out
fork_cnt=0
paul@www:~/Programming/playground/fork#
```

Anyway, the child processes are still running, which you can easily verify by entering `ps` in your shell.